# Netbeans doesn't support javascript

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I had netbeans 6.9, and i was trying to edit javascript on it.  However, I keep getting code errors in my .js files.  I can't even create a new javascript template.  I tried upgrading to netbeans 7.01, but this doesn't change.  I also enabled the JAVA plugin, but it doesn't help.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Works for me...  What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using? Refer to this table: http://netbeans.org/downloads/  PHP means (PHP + HTML + CSS + Javascript)

Comment: I'm currently using the PHP version of netbeans

Comment: Hmmm... How are you getting code errors if you don't get JavaScript support?

Comment: I get a bunch of errors where it says "unclosed character literal" or "character, interface, or enum expected"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get a bunch of errors where it says "unclosed character literal" or
>   "character, interface, or enum expected"

I suspect you've somehow configured NetBeans to handle *.js files as Java, which is an entirely different language.

Go to **Tools-> Options-> Miscellaneous-> Files** and find **js** in the "File Extension" combo. The "Associated File Type (MIME)" input box should say `text/javascript`.

Comment: AHH THIS FIXED IT!  Thank you so much!  I wonder why it reset to java.  Darn thing.

I would vote up if i had the rep count right now. haha

Answer (score 1):

the java-plugin is for java, so this won't help you.

what you'll need is to activate [javascript-support](http://netbeans.org/features/javascript/index.html). javascript is included in the [PHP-pack](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) (and also available as plugin).

to install the plugin, simply click `tools -> plugins` and install `PHP` to enable javascript-(and html-)support.

Comment: I downloaded the PHP package, so that's the problem.  I don't get any options to install the PHP plugin since.. i already downloaded the PHP version of netbeans.

Comment: @perissf: simply click on my link - just because you didn't heard of something doesn't mean it isn't real: http://www.netbeans.com/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=php

Comment: @Handonam: the php-package definitely supports javascript - is it possible you simply have real errors in you code? could you please post some code and the exact error-message netbeans gives for it?

Comment: Here's a simple version that I know works, because my coworker has the same codebase as I do:

Comment: `index.initFilterBehavior = function()
{
  var searchSelector = [
    index.selectors.searchFormTextFields,
    index.selectors.searchFormSelectFields,
    index.selectors.searchFormCheckboxFields,
    index.selectors.searchFormRadioFields
  ].join(', ');
  $(searchSelector).change(function()
  {
    index.initSearchData();
    index.initSearch();
  });
}`

Comment: @perissf: [See all the available Netbean bundles.](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)