# Netbeans 7.0.1 in Ubuntu has no javascript support?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I just installed netbeans 7.0.1 in ubuntu 12.04, and there NO JAVASCRIPT support whatsoever.  I am not getting any errors, but my .js files just appear as regular text files with no syntax highlighting.

My situation is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488976/netbeans-doesnt-support-javascript) because when I go to Tools -> Options -> Misc -> Files, under "Associated File Type (MIME)" i don't have an option for "text/javascript".

Also in my previous installation of netbeans, I could right-click on the "Source Files" folder of my project, select New -> other and I could create a new .JS file like this.  But now there is no option for .js files.  Only PHP (since i installed the PHP plugin), XML, SQL, CSS and a handful of others.

Another thing, I often embed javascript in .php files.  My embedded js just shows up as plain text, no syntax highlighting.

I also checked for additional plugins for JS, but nothing jumped out at me as being the solution.  Does anyone know how I can enable the JS file recognition and syntax highlighting?

Thanks!

** UPDATE **

This installation is acting very weird (when editing text, pressing enter has no reaction, no line return, nothing) so I will try re-installing, will update with results.

** UPDATE 2 **

Installed 7.1 for linux from the netbeans website and everything is working well.  It must have been a faulty installation from the Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 5):

I was using Netbeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.  Installing Netbeans 7.1.2 fixed my color/syntax problems.

For those who need to re-install, here is the download page: http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

Be sure to check Tools -> Options -> Misc -> Files to ensure that everything looks right.

P.S. @jeffery_the_wind Thank you for your update!  This had been driving me crazy today, and I googled for hours and couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Did you originally install Netbeans 7.0.1 from the Ubuntu software center application?

Comment: I think I probably used `sudo apt-get install netbeans`.

Comment: It's an issue with with 7.0.1 that is still present in Ubuntu 12.10's repositoires. There are often issues with NetBeans and/or Oracle's JDK in the official repos so grab the package that Oracle provides with the appropriate version of JDK included [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I've had the same problem in Kubuntu 14.04 and Netbeans 7.0.1. Now I have installed Kubuntu 15.10 and installed Netbeans 8.0.2 via `apt-get` and found the same issue. So I had to download Netbean 8.1 from the official website.